# NHibernate: How do I ignore the cache and go directly to the database?

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Consider a typical NHibernate context class.

```
public class SampleContext : NHibernateContext
{
    public SampleContext(ISession session)
        : base(session)
    { }

    public IQueryable<Person> People
    {
        get { return Session.Linq<Person>(); }
    }

    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        get { return Session.Linq<Person>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id); }
    }
}
```

My question:

> - How could I rewrite the GetPerson method to ignore the cache and retrieve data directly from the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this problem:

1. The Hibernate guys will tell you that you probably should be opening a different session in order to retrieve the latest data from the database.  They would point out that the intention of the session is to be scoped to a relatively short-lived unit of work.
2. You could either put in a call to `Session.Refresh()` inside your `GetPerson()` method to always get the most current state from the database or you could expose that functionality through your own `Refresh()` method.
3. Alternatively, if you have a handle on the `Person` object itself, you could also try a `Session.Evict()` to remove the `Person` object your session cache prior to loading it again.

In my experience, I've tried both #2 and #3 and have eventually always come around to refactoring to do #1.